# Save widget to Image without freeze the UI in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, concurrency

I have a widget with large image with size 2480x3508 pixel and a dynamic QR code in that image that I use code to generate. When I using the RenderRepaintBoundary to save the whole widget include the image and QR code and download it to device with WebImageDownloader, it freeze the UI for about 30s.

When I examine the code, I find out that the part where I convert dart ui.Image into Uint8List with .toByteData method is the main issue, it running very slow to convert Image to byte. How can I solve this issue?

I've tried to use the
**compute** function but it still freeze the UI.

```
class EvoucherPage extends StatelessWidget {
  EvoucherPage({super.key});
  ...
  final GlobalKey genKeyA4 = GlobalKey();

  void download(voucherSize) async {
    ...
    if (voucherSize == "a4") {
      final RenderRepaintBoundary renderRepaintBoundary3 =
          genKeyA4.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
      ui.Image image3 = await renderRepaintBoundary3.toImage();
      final byteData3 = await image3.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      Uint8List data3 = byteData3!.buffer.asUint8List();
      await WebImageDownloader.downloadImageFromUInt8List(
        uInt8List: data3,
        imageQuality: 1,
        name: "voucher_a4",
      );
    }
    ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
                      ElevatedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () {
                          showDialog(
                            barrierDismissible: false,
                            context: context,
                            builder: (context) => const DownloadingDialog(),
                          );
                          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
                                 // Calling compute
                                 compute(download,controller.currentVoucherSize);
                              });
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.download),
                            label: const Text("Tải xuống"),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                ...
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                child: RepaintBoundary(
                                  key: genKeyA4, // Key using here
                                  child: VoucherWidgetA4Download(),
                                ),
                              ),
```

My widget is stateless widget, I tried to precache my image by running the code to get byte data from widget right after the widget build complete but it not work because I using consumer to refresh my widget when I get certain data from sever to generate the QR code, I don't know how to call function to precache byte data in the widget from the controller, and if I know then it still freeze the UI.

At this moment, I just display a dialog to show that image is downloading and prevent user to do anything with barrierdismissed=true and change the image size to 1414x2000 for faster convert to byte data but the quality of image when zoom in not like the original image.

Comment: can you include your compute method and how you;ve call it

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I just added the compute code.

Comment: You should do the computing in another isolate. This way the main isolate is not blocked while you're saving the image. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just reduce the image resolution instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```dart
  Future<void> _heavyTaskHandler() async {
    await compute(download, controller.currentVoucherSize);
  }
.....
   ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: ()async {
          await showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => const DownloadingDialog(),
          );
            // Calling compute
            await  _heavyTaskHandler();//pass data if needed 
          debugPrint("task end");
          },
```

Comment: I tried the code above but still make the UI freezes after clicking the button. Is there any other solution to speed up the conversion of Image data to bytes instead?